# How to pass build directory and the toolchain file to cmake-gui?

Tags: windows, cmake, cmake-gui

I am using CMake on a Windows platform to cross-compile embedded applications. 
Now I would like to use the `cmake-gui` to configure the build. Is it possible to pass the **build directory** and the **toolchain file** to `cmake-gui`?

**Some more background:**
I have a build script which will (1) call `cmake` and `make` to build the application or (2) call `cmake-gui` to configure the build. When the gui starts, the build directory and the toolchain should be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using make as build system, instead of calling `cmake-gui` directly, call:

```
make edit_cache
```

The `edit_cache` target is defined in the main Makefile. Its rule is something like this:

```
edit_cache:
    <path to cmake-gui> -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
```

Note how the source and build directories are passed to the `cmake-gui` program. The toolchain file will be read from the cache.